# SQL ORACLE Polish letters translate

Tags: sql, oracle, translate, polish

I want find a solutions to change letters in sql 
In Polish language we have 'ą','ć','ł','ń'

when i make `select lower(translate(sname,'łńą','lna')) from emplo` it dosn't work as it should be.

help friends :)

Comment: Hi @Artur Stolc. Lower function should be executed before translate. Could you provide sample data?

Comment: @jacek Wróbel select sname, lower(translate(sname,'łńą','lna')) as snamet from emplo;

sname             snamet
Łącka              Łacka
Ńika                Nika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polish letters are stored with the same ascii value as the west european letters, e.g.

```
select ascii('Ł'), ascii('ł'), ascii('L'), ascii('l') from dual;

>> 76 108 76 108
```

You can change the **representation** by changing the character set:

```
select convert('Fuß', 'WE8ISO8859P1', 'US7ASCII') from dual

>> Fu¿
```

Find character sets supported by Oracle by:

```
select * from  V$NLS_VALID_VALUES where parameter = 'CHARACTERSET'
```

Polish character set is ISO 8859-2 (Eastern European)

Comment: and how to view with one is default on database ??

Comment: @ArturStolc default on database: select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';